# Using datatemplates for converting item source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

Lets say I have a `ItemsControl`which is used to render buttons for a list of viewModels

```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModelTypes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Name}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The `PageViewModelTypes`are the view models which are available (For example `OtherViewModel`). For each of the types there is a `DataTemplate` setup with the according views.

```
<dx:DXWindow.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type generalDataViewModel:GeneralViewModel}">
        <generalDataViewModel:GeneralView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type other:OtherViewModel}">
        <other:OtherView />
    </DataTemplate>
</dx:DXWindow.Resources>
```

Is there any way of replacing the `PageViewModelTypes` with the corresponding template types for the `ItemsControl` within the view?

Comment: If you have created a datatemplate for each type of your PageViewModelTypes collection then do you need to define the item template for the ItemsControl? If you dont define the <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> then xaml will pick the corresponding template automatically from your resources section.

Comment: And if that shouldn't work for any reason, you may set an [ItemTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx).

Comment: I still want to render the ViewModels as buttons, not as views, thats why I cannot remove the `DataTemplate`

Comment: @Clemens How would I use the ItemTemplateSelector in this case? I was not able to figure it out...

Comment: So do you want to show the template when the user clicks the relevant button?

Comment: @derape and where/how do you want to show them? separate window? or someother place?

Answer (score 1):

Bind the button content to the item content and your templates will be resolved to the actual types:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Content="{Binding}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This does not work for me, the `OtherViewModel` is still not replaced by `OtherView` types

Comment: Try to reference the templates as ItemsControl's resources or add them to App.xaml

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you explain, how I would do this please? :-)

Comment: I assume that problem is that  resource dictionaries with DataTemplates of your views are not accessible from items control. Just for testing purposes put them in the most common location in app.xaml

Comment: this also can work:
<ItemsControl>  
<ItemsControl.Resources>  
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type generalDataViewModel:GeneralViewModel}">
        <generalDataViewModel:GeneralView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type other:OtherViewModel}">
        <other:OtherView />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Resources>
...
</ItemsControl>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your question is not at all clear. The most common scenario that could fit the vague description you've provided is to have each item in the `ItemsControl` displayed using a `DataTemplate` that corresponds to that type.

Let's call that `Option A`.

But the statement:

> replacing the `PageViewModelTypes` with the corresponding template types for the `ItemsControl` within the view

…could be construed as meaning you want an entirely different data source for the control. I.e. you want to selectively choose a different value for the `ItemsSource` property.

Let's call that `Option B`.

Then later, in the comments, you were asked:

> do you want to show the template when the user clicks the relevant button?

…and you responded "yes"! Even though that's a completely different behavior than either of the above two.

Let's call that `Option C`.

Maybe we can encourage you to provide much-needed clarification. But to do that, it seems most fruitful to start with the simplest, most common scenario. Here is an example of code that implements `Option A`:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO28429768ButtonTemplate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSO28429768ButtonTemplate"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <Window.Resources>
    <local:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="colorToBrushConverter1"/>
    <local:BaseViewModelCollection x:Key="itemsCollection">
      <local:StringViewModel Text="Foo"/>
      <local:StringViewModel Text="Bar"/>
      <local:ColorViewModel Color="Yellow"/>
      <local:ColorViewModel Color="LightBlue"/>  
    </local:BaseViewModelCollection>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:StringViewModel}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ColorViewModel}">
      <Rectangle Width="50" Height="25"
                 Fill="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource colorToBrushConverter1}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource itemsCollection}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Button Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
class BaseViewModelCollection : List<BaseViewModel> { }

class BaseViewModel { }

class StringViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class ColorViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

As you'll see, the `ItemsControl` displays the `Button` instances using its default panel, `StackPanel`. The `Content` of each `Button` is bound to the respective item in the `ItemsSource` collection, a list containing two each of the `StringViewModel` class and the `ColorViewModel` class.

Through defined templates in the window's resources, the content presenter of the button uses the `DataTemplate` associated with each type of view model. Items corresponding to a `StringViewModel` get the template for that type, i.e. a `TextBlock` displaying the text of the view model. Likewise, items corresponding to a `ColorViewModel` instance get the template that displays a rectangle filled with the color from the view model.

If the above does not *exactly* address your question (and it may well not), please edit your question to clarify what you are asking:

- If the above is close, but not precisely what you wanted, please use the above as a reference and explain how what you want to do is different.
- If the above has nothing to do with what you wanted, then ignore it. But do be *specific* about what you actually want, and use precise terminology. For example, if you really want to *replace* the `ItemsSource` with a different collection, then saying you want to replace the `PageViewModelTypes` collection makes sense. But if not, *don't* use a phrase that seems to say exactly that!

Of course, if either `Option B` or `Option C` more closely match what you are trying to do, go ahead and use those as references for your clarifications.

Finally, please check out the very helpful pages [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). They have lots of great information about how you can express yourself in a way that will allow others to *easily* understand what you mean. :)